# Efficiently retain a range of vec elements

Tags: vector, rust

I want a method like this:

```rust
trait RetainRange {
  fn retain_range(&mut self, range: std::ops::Range<usize>);
}

impl<T> RetainRange for Vec<T> {
  fn retain_range(&mut self, range: std::ops::Range<usize>) {
    // Retain only the elements within the given range.
    let mut i = 0usize;
    self.retain(|el| {
      let r = range.contains(&i);
      i += 1;
      r
    });
  }
}
```

But calling a lambda and `range.contains()` every time seems like it might be inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: why not use drain ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain

Answer (score 1):

This code generates what appears to be more efficient assembly.

```rust
  fn retain_range(&mut self, range: std::ops::Range<usize>) {
    self.truncate(range.end);
    if range.start < self.len() {
      self.drain(0..range.start);
    } else {
      self.clear();
    }
  }
```

Adding the `if range.start < self.len()` check avoids a panic if the range is past the end of the `Vec`, and actually also improves the assembly.

Comment: your answer look like the code in your question generated the code in your answer, it's unclear.

Comment: Do you mean I should open an issue to add this method?

Comment: Ah "worst" -> "warrants"?

Comment: Yes, unless we miss something I don't see why this kind of helper function shouldn't be on vec directly.